# "Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'" when compiling Flutter web application

Tags: firebase, flutter

I'm getting this error when i am trying to link my app with firebase on flutter web:

> /C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_storage_web-3.2.9/lib/src/utils/errors.dart:20:20: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
>
> return internals.guardWebExceptions(
>
> ```
>               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> Failed to compile application.

How can i solve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm having the same problem

Comment: thank u guys ...I've solved this problem by adding this package to dependencies on pubspec.yaml
-  cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13

Answer (score 7):

```
firebase_core: ^1.12.0 -> firebase_core: ^1.13.1
cloud_firestore: ^3.1.8 -> cloud_firestore: ^3.1.10
firebase_analytics: ^9.1.0 -> firebase_analytics: ^9.1.2
```

Then do:

```
flutter clean
flutter run
```

This works for me, greetings!

Comment: in short, upgrade to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem by adding this package to dependencies on pubspec.yaml

- cloud_firestore_platform_interface: 5.4.13

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, only need to change this on pubspec.yaml

from `firebase_core: ^1.12.0` to `firebase_core: ^1.13.1`

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error and got a white screen every time.

The other solutions don't work for me.

Why I got this error ?
Answer - probably you have switched from the Flutter Beta version to the flutter Stable version.

My solution
I have not used any **dependency_overrides** on pubspec.yaml as suggested by other StackOverflow solutions.

what I did was updated every firebase related packages to their latest versions then if you're using firebase messageing or firebase notification for your app then check your main.dart where you have initialized every firebase correctly like shown below :-

```
    Future<void> main() async {
  // await dotenv.load();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: const FirebaseOptions(
          apiKey: "xxxxxx-qzNOsF1v4g",
          authDomain: "xx-xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
          databaseURL: "https://xxxx-xxx-x-xxx.xx.com",
          projectId: "xxx-xxxx",
          storageBucket: "xx-xxx.appspot.com",
          messagingSenderId: "xxxxx",
          appId: "1:xxxxx:web:xxxxx",
          measurementId: "G-xxxx")
          );

  await ThemeModeBuilderConfig.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
      .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
          AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
      ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);

  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  setPathUrlStrategy();


  await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 300));

  
  runApp(const MyApp()
      /* MaterialApp(//
  home: MyApp())*/
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can update from firebase_core: ^1.12.0 to firebase_core: ^1.13.1, that will fix the issue

the not recommended way is to use dependency_overrides on pubspec.yaml

```
dependency_overrides:
 firebase_storage_web: 3.2.8
```