# How to solve a guardWebExceptions Web Build Failed Error?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I had to rollback FirebaseRTDB to version 8 and my app is working fine on IOS and Android. When I try to compile to Web, the following errors are appearing:

```
: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': No such file or directory
internals.dart:2
export 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' hide guardWebExceptions;
^

: Error: Error when reading '../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/internals.dart': No such file or directory
internals.dart:6
import 'package:firebase_core/src/internals.dart' as internals;
       ^

: Error: Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'.
internals.dart:11
  return internals.guardWebExceptions(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed to compile application.
```

I have tried the following without success:

1. Restart the pub.dev packages

   flutter clean

   flutter packages get
2. Delete the firebase packages in `pubspec.yaml`, do `flutter packages get`, include them again and do `flutter packages get`.
3. Remove `pubspec.lock` and then do `flutter clean` and `flutter packages get`
4. To execute

   flutter pub cache repair

How can I solve this kind of error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Method not found: 'guardWebExceptions'" when compiling Flutter web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71309168/method-not-found-guardwebexceptions-when-compiling-flutter-web-application)